# How to create dataframe from list in Spark SQL?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Spark version : 2.1

For example, in pyspark, i create a list

`test_list = [['Hello', 'world'], ['I', 'am', 'fine']]`

then how to create a dataframe form the test_list, where the dataframe's type is like below:

`DataFrame[words: array<string>]`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

here is how -

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

cSchema = StructType([StructField("WordList", ArrayType(StringType()))])

# notice extra square brackets around each element of list 
test_list = [['Hello', 'world']], [['I', 'am', 'fine']]

df = spark.createDataFrame(test_list,schema=cSchema)
```

Comment: For anyone who just wants to convert a list of strings and is impressed by the ridiculous lack of proper documentation: you cannot convert 1d objects, you have to transform it into a list of tuples like: [(t,) for t in list_of_strings]

Comment: Is there a reason why `from ... import *`, almost universally considered an antipattern in Python, is advisable here?

Comment: Thanks @Timomo, this helped.

Answer (score 25):

i had to work with multiple columns and types - the example below has one string column and one integer column. A slight adjustment to Pushkr's code (above) gives:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

cSchema = StructType([StructField("Words", StringType())\
                      ,StructField("total", IntegerType())])

test_list = [['Hello', 1], ['I am fine', 3]]

df = spark.createDataFrame(test_list,schema=cSchema)
```

output:

```
 df.show()
 +---------+-----+
|    Words|total|
+---------+-----+
|    Hello|    1|
|I am fine|    3|
+---------+-----+
```

Comment: Same question I asked on another answer: Is there a reason why `from ... import *`, almost universally considered an antipattern in Python, is advisable here?

Answer (score 12):

You should use list of Row objects([Row]) to create data frame.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

spark.createDataFrame(list(map(lambda x: Row(words=x), test_list)))
```

Comment: Should be `spark.createDataFrame`

Answer (score 0):

**If Columns are in different list then use below code as per requirement**

```
l1 =[1,2,3,4]
l2 =['a','b','c','d']
l3=[]
if len(l1)==len(l2):
    for i in range(len(l1)):
        l3.append((l1[i],l2[i]))
print('List:',l3)
column=['Id','Name']
df = spark.createDataFrame(l3,column)
display(df)
**Output:**
List:[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd')]
Id  Name
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
```

Answer (score -3):

```
   You can create a RDD first from the input and then convert to dataframe from the constructed RDD
   <code>  
     import sqlContext.implicits._
       val testList = Array(Array("Hello", "world"), Array("I", "am", "fine"))
       // CREATE RDD
       val testListRDD = sc.parallelize(testList)
     val flatTestListRDD = testListRDD.flatMap(entry => entry)
     // COnvert RDD to DF 
     val testListDF = flatTestListRDD.toDF
     testListDF.show
    </code>
```

Comment: This appears to be Scala code and not Python, for anyone wondering why this is downvoted. The question is explicitly tagged `pyspark`.