# Creating a DataFrame from Row results in 'infer schema issue'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When I began learning PySpark, I used a list to create a `dataframe`. Now that inferring the schema from list has been deprecated, I got a warning and it suggested me to use `pyspark.sql.Row` instead. However, when I try to create one using `Row`, I get infer schema issue. This is my code:

```py
>>> row = Row(name='Severin', age=33)
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(row)
```

This results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 526, in createDataFrame
    rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)
  File "/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 390, in _createFromLocal
    struct = self._inferSchemaFromList(data)
  File "/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 322, in _inferSchemaFromList
    schema = reduce(_merge_type, map(_infer_schema, data))
  File "/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 992, in _infer_schema
    raise TypeError("Can not infer schema for type: %s" % type(row))
TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <type 'int'>
```

So I created a schema

```py
>>> schema = StructType([StructField('name', StringType()), 
...                      StructField('age',IntegerType())])
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(row, schema)
```

but then, this error gets thrown.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 526, in createDataFrame
    rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)
  File "/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 387, in _createFromLocal
    data = list(data)
  File "/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 509, in prepare
    verify_func(obj, schema)
  File "/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1366, in _verify_type
    raise TypeError("StructType can not accept object %r in type %s" % (obj, type(obj)))
TypeError: StructType can not accept object 33 in type <type 'int'>
```

Comment: Here is an example from the documentation: [EXAMPLE](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create dataframe from list in Spark SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43444925/how-to-create-dataframe-from-list-in-spark-sql)

Comment: @Jeremy Did you even go through the question? I clearly said I knew how to create a `DataFrame` from a `list` but I get error when I create one using `pyspark.sql.Row`. And I got the answer for my question from @Daniel De Paula below. Go through the question at least once before marking something as a duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `createDataFrame` function takes a **list of Rows** (among other options) plus the schema, so the correct code would be something like:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row

schema = StructType([StructField('name', StringType()), StructField('age',IntegerType())])
rows = [Row(name='Severin', age=33), Row(name='John', age=48)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema)

df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

Out:

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: integer (nullable = true)

+-------+---+
|   name|age|
+-------+---+
|Severin| 33|
|   John| 48|
+-------+---+
```

In the pyspark docs ([link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame.html)) you can find more details about the createDataFrame function.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just making a pandas dataframe, you can convert each Row to a dict and then rely on pandas' type inference, if that's good enough for your needs. This worked for me:

```
import pandas as pd

sample = output.head(5) #this returns a list of Row objects

df = pd.DataFrame([x.asDict() for x in sample])
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem recently and the answers here helped me untderstand the problem better.

my code:

```
row = Row(name="Alice", age=11)  
spark.createDataFrame(row).show()
```

resulted in a very similar error:

```
An error was encountered:  
Can not infer schema for type: <class 'int'>  
Traceback ...
```

the **cause of the problem**:
createDataFrame expects an **array of rows**. So if you only have one row and don't want to invent more, simply make it an array: **[row]**

```
row = Row(name="Alice", age=11)
spark.createDataFrame([row]).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a list of type Row and pass that list  with schema to your `createDataFrame()` method. sample example

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
department1 = Row(id='AAAAAAAAAAAAAA', type='XXXXX',cost='2')
department2 = Row(id='AAAAAAAAAAAAAA', type='YYYYY',cost='32')
department3 = Row(id='BBBBBBBBBBBBBB', type='XXXXX',cost='42')
department4 = Row(id='BBBBBBBBBBBBBB', type='YYYYY',cost='142')
department5 = Row(id='BBBBBBBBBBBBBB', type='ZZZZZ',cost='149')
department6 = Row(id='CCCCCCCCCCCCCC', type='XXXXX',cost='15')
department7 = Row(id='CCCCCCCCCCCCCC', type='YYYYY',cost='23')
department8 = Row(id='CCCCCCCCCCCCCC', type='ZZZZZ',cost='10')

schema = StructType([StructField('id', StringType()), StructField('type',StringType()),StructField('cost', StringType())])
rows = [department1,department2,department3,department4,department5,department6,department7,department8 ]
df = spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema)
```