# How can I load data from a json file, containing array of arrays and not objects into a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I've tried using the following code after looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/50969995 but I've understood that `createDataFrame` from the answer is different compared to `spark.read.json` and cannot be used in same way.

```py
import findspark
findspark.init('/home/myuser/softwareInstallations/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7')
import pyspark

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, IntegerType, StringType, ArrayType, FloatType

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Basics').getOrCreate()
data_schema = StructType([StructField('col1', IntegerType(), False),
                StructField('col2', IntegerType(), False),
                StructField('col3', FloatType(), False)])

df1 = spark.read.json('myfile.json', schema=data_schema)
df1.printSchema()
df1.show()
```

The answer link I shared demonstrated how to get array of 2 length arrays into df. How could I do the same for a data in a file. My data looks like this in the `myfile.json`.

```json
[
  [58808,2,0.103],
  [58807,2,0.77345],
  [58805,1,0.05],
  [58804,4,0.58475]
]
```

I'm new to python and pyspark guys, hopefully you wont mistake my lack of understanding as laziness XD.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample file contains multi-line JSON strings. In Spark when reading JSON there are two options supported and you have to use `option("multiline", "true")`:

1. single line mode - splittable
2. multi-line mode - non-splittable

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
)
multiline_df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json(
    "myfile.json"
)
multiline_df.printSchema()
multiline_df.show()
```